# How would you upgrade the terraform eks module?

Tags: terraform, upgrade, amazon-eks

I've created a few EKS clusters using terraform AWS-EKS module when it was using version 12.0.0.

Now when I want to create new clusters, the module has upgraded to version 18.0.0+ (it has many breaking changes) and it's a bit harder to create, but I'll manage.

Question is - how would you upgrade the existing clusters created using the old module to the newer version?

Keep in mind Im not looking to upgrade k8s, but the module version.

Comment: You can set the version you want by using `version`.

Comment: Setting the version doesn't cut it this time - I want to upgrade the previously set version from 12.0.0 to 18.0.7 - quite the large upgrade path with many breaking changes.

Answer (score 0):

I usually proceed reading the documentation too find some big changes, updating the version constraint in `module` block and after that running `terraform plan` for see if everything is like expected or there are some errors.

Of course if you can do all in a test environment (if you already have it or creating it using a Terraform Workspace) is better.

Comment: RTFM is basic :) the issue is that there is no clear upgrade path and a lot of versions have passed.  I will probably try to create an old test cluster and try to upgrade it.